# Effective Java Item 66: Why to synchronize both read and write methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, effective-java

In Effective Java -> Item 66, Joshua stresses on the need to synchronize both read and write operations to avoid liveness failure.

Here in this particular example, I think synchronization on write method is redundant. Even after removing synchronize on write method, program runs and terminates without any issue. 
   Synchronize is needed to see consistent state of an object, which is achieved through synchronize on read method.

Please let me know your views on this.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopThread {

private static boolean stopRequested;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (!isStopRequested())
                i++;
        }
    }).start();
    ;
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    setStopRequested(true);
}

private static synchronized boolean isStopRequested() {
    return stopRequested;
}

private static void setStopRequested(boolean stopRequested) {
    StopThread.stopRequested = stopRequested;
}
}
```

Comment: Only 1 thread is calling this, what do you want?
Moreover, your get/set function is too simple, the primitive operation is synchronized itself

Comment: I haven't looked at this yet... but for multi-threading and synchronization issues, you can't conclude there isn't a problem just because you run it and it works.  The order in which threads execute their operations is unpredictable if they're not synchronized, which means that if you run it twice, you might have thread 1 performing some operation first one time, and thread 2 the next time, with different results.  To determine whether the code is correct, you really have to consider every possible execution order and combination of orders.

Comment: Don't confuse "the program runs fine" with "the program will always run fine". Not exercising the failure condition doesn't mean that the failure condition is absent.

Comment: @kidnan1991, false and false. There are two threads (main, and the one explicitly created). And boolean writes are *atomic* (in that you don't see partial writes), just not necessarily *visible* to subsequent reads; if they were "synchronized", there would be no need for `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @Omkar, read up on _happens-before_ in the Java memory model.

Comment: @LewBloch, As I understand from `happens-before` relationship, in this particular case synchronize on write method of `main` thread will update the main memory with latest boolean value. Hence, synchronized read method will be able to see the updated value. So, without synchronize we leave it to JVM to update main memory. Hence, my above program could behave inconsistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you have mentioned could be best suited to demonstrate how in **absence of synchronization (or volatile) there is no guarantee about when the values from thread local memory would be flushed to main memory**, but this example is certainly not best suited to demonstrate the "read-write concurrency issues".

I think you might have mis-understood the purpose of example, the purpose was to show the effect of thread communication in absence of synchronization. Read below excerpt from same item #66:

> The actions of the synchronized methods in StopThread would be atomic even without synchronization. **In other words, the
>   synchronization on these methods is used solely for its communication
>   effects, not for mutual exclusion.**

The reason why you think it is working is because in absence of synchronization JVM makes no "**guarantee**" when the values from the thread local memory would be flushed to the main memory, which means that it may not flush at all or it may flush but "when" is not guaranteed. When you run it, then values are getting flushed but it is not necessary that it will always get flushed, so that's where "guarantee" comes into picture, if you use synchronization (or volatile, depending on scenario) then JVM guarantees the "**happens-before**" relationship, which is nothing but guarantee that flushing of values from thread local memory to main memory would "happen before" any thread could read the values from main memory.

A better example to check the effect of read-write related concurrency issue in absence of synchronization could be the popular bank account debit credit example, below is quick sample:

```
public class AccountDebitCredit {

    private int accountBalance = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final AccountDebitCredit accountDebitCredit = new AccountDebitCredit();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    // if you remove synchronization from t1 and t2, then there would be concurrency issues.
                    synchronized (accountDebitCredit) {
                        accountDebitCredit.accountBalance = accountDebitCredit.accountBalance + 100;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    // if you remove synchronization from t1 and t2, then there would be concurrency issues.
                    synchronized (accountDebitCredit) {
                        accountDebitCredit.accountBalance = accountDebitCredit.accountBalance - 100;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println(accountDebitCredit.accountBalance);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(accountDebitCredit.accountBalance);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modified your code and now it doesn't finish at all. When you do not use atomic variables you never now what happens next. JIT can optimize away you read/write operaions.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopThread {

    private static boolean stopRequested = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested)
                    i++;
            }
        }).start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        stopRequested = true;
        System.out.println("Set to true");
        Thread.sleep(40 * 1000L);
    }
}
```

On my machine this code never finishes. Since modified code does almost the same work it's easy to see that you are relying on JIT behavior which can change in future. Maybe in next java version you code will not be able to finish too.

Comment: I tried your example by decreasing values you have used, I used `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` and `Thread.sleep(4 * 1000L);` and program finishes, I think if you use these values you will get same result, or may be not, but the whole point is that in absence of synchronization (or volatile) there is no guarantee about when the values from thread local memory would be flushed to main memory.

Comment: @hagrawal for one second the program on my machine still finishes, yep. I used 10 sec to make sure the code in the loop will get compiled. With 4 second waiting it doesn't finish. So it seems it depends on jdk version and OS/CPU architecture.

Comment: @hagrawal not sure about thread local memory, it's some old stuff and doesn't exist in current java version. There is CPU store buffer which caches writes and it's flushed with memory barrier. So yes, if you do not use volatile, then in theory it can be delayed indefinitely.

Comment: "*I used 10 sec to make sure the code in the loop will get compiled.*" - whether you put 10 seconds or nothing, it wouldn't matter, JIT doesn't depend upon these delays, the way JIT works is that JVM will keep track of how many times a method is getting called and once "JIT compilation threshold" is reached it will optimize it, so it doesn't depend upon any sleep or delay. "*not sure about thread local memory, it's some old stuff and doesn't exist in current java version*" this is nothing local memory of thread with processor cache, you may call it by different names but concept remains same.

Comment: @hagrawal I understand how JIT works. I made a delay 10 seconds to make sure the code in the loop will execute enough times to compile. If I set delay to 1 second then the code will finish. Do you have the same result or the code always finish on your machine?

Comment: I used 10 seconds - `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);`, but I kept other one with 4 seconds - `Thread.sleep(4 * 1000L);` (anyways it shouldn't matter), and still my program finishes.